# Parsing json with Powershell in cURL

Tags: powershell, curl

Hi I am trying to execute below ways to run the POST call in power shell

option 1:

```
$Body="{ \`"cartItem\`" : {\`"sku\`" : \`"RG1219013\`", \`"qty\`" : \`"1\`",  \`"quoteId\`" : \`"QRAeZdoFbieEWHjrRs5X0G1tHRE4el30\`"  }}"
```

option 2:

```
$Body=@"
{ \"cartItem\" : {\"sku\" : \"RG1219013\", \"qty\" : \"1\",  \"quoteId\" : \"QRAeZdoFbieEWHjrRs5X0G1tHRE4el30\"  }}
"@
```

option3 :

```
$Body = @{
    cartItem =
    {
        sku = 'RG1219013'
        qty = '1'
        quoteId = 'QRAeZdoFbieEWHjrRs5X0G1tHRE4el30'
    }
} 

$Json = (ConvertTo-Json $Body)
```

Execute:

```
$Header = @{ "Content-Type" = "application/json" }
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Body $Body -Uri $UriAddtoCart -Header $Header
```

In `option 1` and `option 2` I am getting Bad request (400) and `option 3` it's internal error (500)

Below jason respond successfully through postman

```
{
    "cartItem" :
    {
        "sku" : "RG1219013",
        "qty" : "1",
        "quoteId" : "QRAeZdoFbieEWHjrRs5X0G1tHRE4el30"
    }
}
```

Is there anything missing here?

Comment: option 3 looks fine, option 1 and 2 are tricky to escape correctly so i'd prefer option3 other theese. error 500 means something on the server-side is going wrong and does not neccesairily mean your request or json is bad. do you get any error message from that webservice ? are you missing something in the header ?

Comment: @D.J.Yes I get the response when I tried same thing with Postman. Only that `Content-Type` header is there

Comment: You missing a `@` sign after `cartItem =` in option 3 (this way you assign it a function), Thus:  `cartItem = {...` should be: `cartItem = @{...` (check the actual  content of the `$Json` file)

Comment: @iRon That's it. All good.

Comment: @iRon you should post that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Json file is missing a @ sign after `cartItem =` in option 3 (this way a function is assigned to the `cartItem` property rather than a HashTable)
This will get clear if you output the `$Json` file (e.g. `Write-Host $Json`).

Thus:

```
$Body = @{
    cartItem =
    {
        sku = 'RG1219013'
        ...
```

Should be:

```
$Body = @{
    cartItem =
    @{
        sku = 'RG1219013'
        ...
```